# How can I run javascript file in atom editor?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

I have installed "script" package in my atom editor. When I try to run my .js file it gives me a failure message. I have also installed git and nodejs. What can I do? How can I solve it? message looks like

> 'C:\Users\Muhammad' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>    operable program or batch file.

[image]

Comment: Please add some relevant code, perhaps your `hello.js` file.

Comment: In general, if you have a terminal, `node hello.js` will work, assuming everything is properly set up.

Comment: here is my simple code

console.log("Hello worlds");